# Dreamweaver's rollover image not working with IE10

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, dreamweaver, rollover

I've a problem with IE10 and Dreamweaver's rollover image. In my homepage I put 6 rollover images, and one of these pictures is show like broken image (look the link below)... I don't know why...

This is what I see in IE10:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9t9caq2ybnwvk0/IE10.jpg

This is my webpage folder:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tcy03ck2od4w9mq/index.zip

This is my relevant code:

```
<div id="div_arch" class="fluid"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('arch','','roll_home/BN-div_arch.JPG',1)"><img id="arch" src="roll_home/div_arch.JPG" alt=""></a><h2 class="text">EDILIZIA</h2></div>
<div id="div_strutt" class="fluid"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('strutt','','roll_home/BN-div_strutt.JPG',1)"><img id="strutt" src="roll_home/div_strutt.JPG" alt=""></a><h2 class="text">STRUTTURE</h2></div>
<div id="div_imp" class="fluid"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('imp','','roll_home/BN-div_impianti.JPG',1)"><img id="imp" src="roll_home/div_impianti.JPG" alt=""></a><h2 class="text">IMPIANTI</h2></div>
<div id="div_formaz" class="fluid"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('formaz','','roll_home/BN-div_formaz.JPG',1)"><img id="formaz" src="roll_home/div_formaz.JPG" alt=""></a><h2 class="text">FORMAZIONE</h2></div>
<div id="div_amb" class="fluid"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('ambient','','roll_home/BN-div_amb.jpg',1)"><img id="ambient" src="roll_home/div_amb.jpg" alt=""></a><h2 class="text">AMBIENTE</h2></div>
<div id="div_sicur" class="fluid"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('sicurez','','roll_home/BN-div_sicur.jpg',1)"><img id="sicurez" src="roll_home/div_sicur.jpg" alt=""></a><h2 class="text">SICUREZZA</h2></div>
```

Can you help me please? Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make it easy for us to help you -- post the relevant code directly into the question, and if possible, provide a working demonstration of your problem on a site like http://jsfiddle.net . Additionally, please explain exactly what you mean by "not working".

Comment: And this is what I see in Chrome and Firefox:

![IE10](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2faqrfe4jecw5xm/chrome_ff.jpg)

Comment: I'd start by double-checking your capitalization and spelling of the filenames, especially those `jpg/JPG` extensions.

Comment: What you mean by "double-checking"?

Comment: Just check again. Verify that your file names are 100% accurate.

Comment: Nobody knows why in IE10 there isn't the picture in the center of the second line? Its code is the same of the other pictures!

Comment: have you turned on IE's Compatibility Mode?